# Returning content after Mapping is wrong (Automapper .NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I use automapper to map from entity to dto.

In appservice method I need to get all values from DB and push it to list

Here is my method

```
 public class ExperienceAppService : IExperience
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ExperienceAppService(ApplicationDbContext context,
        IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<List<ExperienceListDto>> GetExperiences()
    {
        var experiences = await _context.Experiences
            .ProjectTo<ExperienceListDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();
        return experiences;
    }
```

}

Here is mapping profile

```
 public class MappingsProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingsProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<UserDto, User>();

        #region Experiences

        CreateMap<ExperienceDto, Experience>();
        CreateMap<Experience, ExperienceDto>().ForMember(x => x.Name,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(n => n.Name))
            .ForMember(x => x.City, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.City))
            .ForMember(x => x.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Price))
            .ForMember(x => x.Rating, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Rating));

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is how I register it in Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                    ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        //Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingsProfile>());
        services.AddAutoMapper();
```

My problem, that in response I get text like this

> > {   "stateMachine": {
> >         "<>1__state": 0,
> >         "<>t__builder": {},
> >         "<>4__this": {}   },   "context": {},   "moveNextAction": {
> >         "method": {
> >           "name": "MoveNext",
> >           "declaringType": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TooSeeWeb.Core.DtoModels.Experiences.ExperienceListDto,
> >     TooSeeWeb.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> >     Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure.AppServices.Experiences.ExperienceAppService+<GetExperiences>d__3,
> >     TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> >     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
> >           "reflectedType": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TooSeeWeb.Core.DtoModels.Experiences.ExperienceListDto,
> >     TooSeeWeb.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> >     Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure.AppServices.Experiences.ExperienceAppService+d__3,
> >     TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> >     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
> >           "memberType": 8,
> >           "metadataToken": 100682290,
> >           "module": {
> >             "mdStreamVersion": 131072,
> >             "fullyQualifiedName": "/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Private.CoreLib.dll",
> >             "moduleVersionId": "9aeda1ea-7722-4ca6-a7ca-c000af27dec0",
> >             "metadataToken": 1,

Aтв much more code, and in the end, I get values from method. Where is my problem can be?

Answer (score 4):

My problem was not in mapper. 
In Controller, I was returning a list like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetExperiences()
    {
        var experiences = _experienceAppService.GetExperiences();
        return Ok(experiences);
    }
```

Instead of this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetExperiences()
    {
        var experiences = _experienceAppService.GetExperiences();
        return Ok(experiences.Result);
    }
```

Comment: `[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetExperiences()
    {
        var experiences = await _experienceAppService.GetExperiences();
        return Ok(experiences);
    }`
That's a better way of having `async` methods